# How to make a statement that checks if something is divisible by something else without a remainder (BASH)

Tags: unix, bash, script

```
#!/bin/bash


Echo “Enter a number”

Read  $number

If [$number ] ; then 

Echo “Your number is divisible by 5”

Else

Echo “Your number is not divisible by 5”

fi
```

the if [$number] statement is what I don't know how to set up

Comment: Welcome, Roger. Can you please wrap the code in your question in code tags (or use the code button on the editor)? It makes things a *lot* easier to read.

Answer (score 47):

You can use a simpler syntax in Bash than some of the others shown here:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a number " number    # read can output the prompt for you.
if (( $number % 5 == 0 ))           # no need for brackets
then
    echo "Your number is divisible by 5"
else
    echo "Your number is not divisible by 5"
fi
```

Comment: thanks!  i knew there had to be a simpler way but wasn't having any luck.  bash scripting has always been a bit of a black art to me.

Comment: This will result in the error message, "((: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")" and "((: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")" see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=677751 for explanation.

Comment: @RedCricket: Only if you enter a leading zero. If that's an issue, you can do: `if (( 10#$number % 5 == 0 ))` to force `$number` to be interpreted as base 10 (instead of base 8/octal implied by the leading zero).

Comment: @Deniis Williamson Yes that is more accurate. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 11):

No **bc** needed as long as it's integer math (you'll need bc for floating point though):  In bash, the **(( ))** operator works like **expr**.

As others have pointed out the operation you want is **modulo (%)**.

```
#!/bin/bash  

echo "Enter a number"
read number

if [ $(( $number % 5 )) -eq 0 ] ; then
   echo "Your number is divisible by 5"
else
   echo "Your number is not divisible by 5"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

How about using the `bc` command:

```
!/usr/bin/bash

echo “Enter a number”
read number
echo “Enter divisor”
read divisor
remainder=`echo "${number}%${divisor}" | bc`
echo "Remainder: $remainder"

if [ "$remainder" == "0" ] ; then
        echo “Your number is divisible by $divisor”
else
        echo “Your number is not divisible by $divisor”
fi
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use expr instead of bc: remainder=`expr $number % $divisor`

Comment: @Dan Yes it should suffice for the OP. However, I think since `bc` specialises in calculations, it can handle stuff like 33.3 % 11.1 which `expr` would likely choke on.

Comment: would definitely choke; expr and (( )) only handle integer math.

Answer (score 3):

Nagul's answer is great, but just fyi, the operation you want is modulus (or modulo) and the operator is generally `%`.

Answer (score 2):

I have done it in a different way. Check if it works for you.
**Example 1 :**

```
num=11;
[ `echo $num/3*3 | bc` -eq $num ] && echo "is divisible" || echo "not divisible"
Output : not divisible
```

**Example 2 :**

```
num=12;
[ `echo $num/3*3 | bc` -eq $num ] && echo "is divisible" || echo "not divisible"
Output : is divisible
```

Simple logic.

12 / 3 = 4
4 * 3 = 12 --> same number

11 / 3 = 3
3 * 3 = 9 --> not same number

Answer (score 0):

Just in the interest of syntax neutrality and mending the overt infix notation bias around these parts, I've modified nagul's solution to use `dc`.

```
!/usr/bin/bash

echo “Enter a number”
read number
echo “Enter divisor”
read divisor
remainder=$(echo "${number} ${divisor}%p" | dc)
echo "Remainder: $remainder"

if [ "$remainder" == "0" ]
then
        echo “Your number is divisible by $divisor”
else
        echo “Your number is not divisible by $divisor”
fi
```

Comment: I realize that this is a really old question but I have a question about the code. I'm relatively new to bash and just tried to run this script. However it gives me a few errors and I honestly don't know why. After entering the number and divisor I get: 

test.sh: 7: test.sh: dc: not found

Remainder: 

test.sh: 10: [: unexpected operator

“Your number is not divisible by 2”  



Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @AreusAstarte: It means you don't have `dc` installed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `expr` like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "Enter a number: "
read number
if [ `expr $number % 5` -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Your number is divisible by 5"
else
    echo "Your number is not divisible by 5"
fi
```